# getting jquery autocomplete to pass item to another field when selected

Tags: php, jquery, json, autocomplete

I've been working on this for a couple of hours and it should work but i'm missing something!

basically, i'm using jquery autocomplete with json source, with 2 values id and description.
Description should show up in suggestions and if item is selected and ID passed to a hidden field ( the field is not hidden currently for testing purposes)

here's my code:

```
$(function() {
  $("#CurrentProv").autocomplete({
   source: "inc/provider_term.php",
   minLength: 3,
    formatItem: function(data, i, n, value) {   
        return  value.split("|")[1];
          } 
    });
      $("#CurrentProv").result(function(event, data, formatted) {
      if (data)
            $("input#fid").val(data[0]);
      });
});
```

//PHP valid json output

```
$term = $_GET['term'];

$sql = "SELECT * FROM db.table WHERE PName LIKE '%$term%'";
$res = mysql_query($sql, $conn) or die(mysql_error());

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($res)) {

$searchArray['value'] = $row['PID'].'|'.$row['PName'];
$search[] = $searchArray;

}

echo json_encode($search);
```

I've searched and done various variations and still doesn't work!!! My brain is shutting down!!!!!!!!

Comment: The PHP script is vulnerable to SQL injection attacks. Hopefully what you have given us here is just an example and not earmarked as production code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, switch to using the actual jQuery UI [autocomplete](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/).

You'll have to sort out how to format your items on the server side, or in your JSON callback, because formatItems is not supported anymore.  Check out this [guide](http://www.learningjquery.com/2010/06/autocomplete-migration-guide) for some help.

Now that you've done that, here's how it will look:

```
$(function() {
 $("#CurrentProv").autocomplete({
   source: "inc/provider_term.php", //or you can use a callback here
   minLength: 3,
   change: function(event, ui) {
      $("input#fid").val(ui.item.value);//or ui.item.desc perhaps
   }
});
```

});

Answer (score 0):

Working tweaked PHP code and JS as Ryley suggested:

```
$term = $_GET['term'];

$sql = "SELECT * FROM db.table WHERE PName LIKE '%$term%'";
$res = mysql_query($sql, $conn) or die(mysql_error());

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($res)) {

$searchArray['value'] = $row['PID'];
$searchArray['id'] = $row['PName'];
$search[] = $searchArray;

}

echo json_encode($search);


$(function() {
 $("#CurrentProv").autocomplete({
   source: "inc/provider_term.php", //or you can use a callback here
   minLength: 3,
   change: function(event, ui) {
      $("input#fid").val(ui.item.id);//or ui.item.desc perhaps
   }
});
```