# Passing back multiple variables using json_encode and using those variable in multiple fields

Tags: php, jquery, json

OK so I am fairly new to JSON. I have been trying to figure out this for a few hours now with no success, so time to ask around I guess.

I have a form that is searching the database for a user based on first or last name. I have it displaying the full name of results, however when the correct result is selected I want to set the value of another hidden field with the user's id. I need to pass the id back to the form using JSON. The form will use the id within the database.

**HTML**

```
<form action="" method="POST">
    <div class="form-group input-group">
        <input type="text" id="user" name="user" class="form-control">
        <span class="input-group-btn"><button class="btn btn-default" name="addUser" type="button"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></button></span>
    </div>
</form>
```

**jQuery**

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $("#user").autocomplete({
            source: 'user-search.php'
        });
    });
</script>
```

**user-search.php**

```
$query = 'SELECT * FROM user WHERE firstname LIKE "%'.$term.'%" OR lastname LIKE "%'.$term.'%" ORDER BY lastname ASC';
$query = mysqli_query($db,$query);
while($r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    $data[] = $r['lastname'].', '.$r['firstname'];
}
echo json_encode($data);
```

Comment: read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3442606/getting-jquery-autocomplete-to-pass-item-to-another-field-when-selected